# FastAPI, SQLalchemy; By using Postman I can't post raw JSON body request correctly. It works fine with params not with raw JSON body

Tags: python, database, postgresql, postman, fastapi

My @router.post is like this:

```
@router.post("/filter/filtering")
async def filter_test(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, company_name: str = None, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    _audits = crud.filter_test(db, company_name)
    return Response(status="Ok", code="200", message="Success fetch all data", result=_audits)
```

From crud.py, filter_test function is:

```
def filter_test(db: Session, company_name: str = None):
    # if company_name:
    return db.query(Audit).filter(Audit.company_name == company_name).all()
```

When I post request with params as "company_name" as key and "panda" as value, it gives me correct answers. But when I try to do it in a Body format, fails me.

With params output:

```
{
    "code": "200",
    "status": "Ok",
    "message": "Success fetch all data",
    "result": [
        {
            "product_name": "dondurma",
            "audit_date": "2022-06-06T00:00:00",
            "request_date": "2022-11-14T18:11:29.450855",
            "correct_company_name": null,
            "company_name": "panda",
            "image_link": "www.test.com",
            "id": 5,
            "correct_name": null,
            "correction_date": null
        },
        {
            "product_name": "dondurma1",
            "audit_date": "2022-06-06T00:00:00",
            "request_date": "2022-11-14T18:40:18.925370",
            "correct_company_name": null,
            "company_name": "panda",
            "image_link": "www.test.com",
            "id": 6,
            "correct_name": null,
            "correction_date": null
        },
        {
            "product_name": "dondurma1",
            "audit_date": "2022-06-06T00:00:00",
            "request_date": "2022-11-14T18:40:18.925370",
            "correct_company_name": null,
            "company_name": "panda",
            "image_link": "www.test.com",
            "id": 7,
            "correct_name": null,
            "correction_date": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my JSON BODY format:

```
{
    "parameter":{
        
        "company_name":"panda"


    }
}
```

This one is the output of the JSON Body format:

```
{
    "code": "200",
    "status": "Ok",
    "message": "Success fetch all data",
    "result": [
        {
            "product_name": "dondurma1",
            "audit_date": "2022-06-06T00:00:00",
            "request_date": "2022-11-14T18:40:18.925370",
            "correct_company_name": "kratos",
            "company_name": null,
            "image_link": "www.test.com",
            "id": 8,
            "correct_name": "kratos",
            "correction_date": null
        }
    ]
}
```

What might be the problem is? Thanks in advance

Tried with params, it works fine as for json body format it fails. Screenshot for postman is here:
[image]

Comment: Why do you use `parameters` key in your body? That is not necessary? You get all companies with name is null, because you don’t set the company name with your body.

Comment: Sadly, I'm beginner to begin with, sorry for those mistakes. 

I corrected body as:

{
    "company_name": "panda"
}

but still getting same null irrelevant result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to define a pydantic model as the body, or else use `Body` which is fine in your case as you're only accepting one value:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import Body  # not mentioning all the other fastapi imports here for brevity

@router.post("/filter/filtering")
async def filter_test(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, company_name: Optional[str] = Body(default=None, embed=True), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    _audits = crud.filter_test(db, company_name)
    return {'status': "Ok", 'code': "200", 'message': "Success fetch all data", 'result': _audits}
```

This will work passing a request body of `{}` or `{"company_name": null}` or `{"company_name": "foo"}` - the first two cases the `company_name` variable will default to None.

The `Response` in your example doesn't work for me if it's a fastAPI `Response`, is that a custom class you have? Here I'm just returning a dictionary which will work fine provided it's json serializable.

You might consider dropping the status and code from that dict as the framework is already returning HTTP status 200 by default (i.e. not part of the body), or you can pass a custom status_code via returning a `JSONResponse`.

Comment: Thank you mate! I was going hard to solve this problem but solution was adding embed=True in the Body().

Thanks!